# add to cart button didnt shown in the bottom of the description

Tags: php

*the addtocart button appear on the top of picture. only one button for all product. how to make each product have their own addtocart buttton?

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 15    
");
$i=0;
$dyn_table='<table border="1" cellpadding="10">';
$name = 'name';
$image = 'image';
$category = 'category';
$color = 'color';
$description = 'description';
$price = 'price';

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

$product_id=$row['product_id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$image = $row['image'];
$category = $row['category'];
$color = $row['color'];
$description = $row['description'];
$price = $row['price'];
$image = $row['image'];

if($i % 5 == 0){
$dyn_table.='<tr><td>'.$name.'<br /><img src="img/'.$image.'" width="200"     
height="90" align="center"><br /><p>'.$description.'</p></td>'
.'<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart $product_id" 
/>';
} else {
$dyn_table.='<td>'.$name.'<br /><img src="img/'.$image.'" width="200"   
height="90" align="center"><br /><p>'.$description.'</p></td>';
}
$i++; }
$dyn_table.='</tr></table>';
?>

<?php echo $dyn_table;?>
```

Comment: tq panther for the editing  :)

Comment: what is the use of `$i % 5===0` condition? i think it is useless there

Comment: i want to make 5 image appear in right for each column. -sorry,i have bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You could use foreach function to loop through each value and place add to cart button

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
       foreach($row as $value){
         //you data $vlaue[]
              ?>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
         <?php
         }
  }
```